# Get current time crossplatform in c++

Tags: c++, time

How can I get current time (I need hours, minutes, seconds) crossplatform in c++? I saw here  make structure of values but there are a lots of another stuff that I don't need. And memory is very important here.

Comment: Our time is also important here. Please clarify your question and/or read your C++ compiler's documentation.

Comment: I saw a structure where localtime function fills values like year, month and another. But I need to get directly what I need except that all.

Comment: What is the possible reason for upvoting a badly expressed question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The routines in `<time.h>` are cross-platform and in fact required to be available for conforming implementations of ISO C.  Use `time` to retrieve the elapsed time since 1970, and `localtime` or `gmtime` to break that down into hours, minutes, and seconds, as needed.

You shouldn't be concerned that `struct tm` uses too much memory to store unneeded fields unless you are programming **extremely** memory-constrained devices, in which case you probably aren't looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: The routines in what are cross-platform? You seem to be missing a noun.

Comment: Sorry, I guess unescaped anglies in StackOverflow are a no-no.  <time.h>Hello, world!</time.h>